# Print numbers from 1-50

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
x=1
while [ $x -le 50 ]
do
    echo $x
    $x=(($x + 1))
done
```

I have wrote the above code. What seems to be a easy task in many programming languages is giving this error for me.

```
solution.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
solution.sh: line 5: `    $x=(($x + 1))'
```

How to debug errors in bash. Is there any IDE?

Comment: Use `bash -x scriptname` to debug.

Comment: There are 2 mistakes. The line should be `x=$(($x + 1))`. But easy to use `seq` instead all script `seq 50`

Comment: Its working even if i do not keep a $ attached to x inside the parantheses. What is the difference

Comment: Just so you know, in bash, you can do `echo {1..50}`. And in `$(())` environment, the variables inside are automatically evaluated, which is why you don't need the `$` inside it again.

Comment: Thanks, @muru I started 10 mins back. thinking of doing it in normal way first.

Comment: @WannaBeCoder you are using let and could also just do  `((x++))`. Also look up the `let` command.

Comment: If they use `$(($x+1))` that will work but `(($x+1))` will not, look on http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html for more info

Comment: @Jidder Since I specifically said `$(())`, I don't see how I am incorrect. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html

Comment: @muru Sorry, misread and thought OP was talking about their original code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On line 5:
Change `$x=(($x + 1))` to `x=$(($x + 1))`.

Instead of using an entire bash script, you can just use `seq 1 50`.

If the case were `x=$(($x + 2))`, you could use `seq 1 2 50`, where 2 denotes step/increment.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `x=$(( x + 1 ))` ? No dollar symbol within the double brackets.

Comment: @garethTheRed, `$((x + 1))` would not work with some old versions of ash based shells, and is currently not clearly specified by POSIX (under discussion there) but would work in most shells nowadays. `$(($x + 1))` is clearly specified but `$((1-$x))` for instance has issues that `$((1-x))` (or `x=$((1-($x)))`) don't have. `x=$((x + 1))` is safe in modern versions of ash based shells even if `x` doesn't contain a number. Both have security implications in most other shells.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the question is tagged `bash`. Does it matter what happens elsewhere?

Comment: @muru, to many people, yes, it does. And my comment was not addressed to the OP (and besides is just general information on the benefit of either in the general case).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Before commenting, I tested `x=$(($x + 1))` and it errored for me.  I've tried it again and now it works. Aargh!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - [here there is this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) : *...intentionally silent about how a variable's numeric value in an expression is determined from its normal "sequence of bytes" value... conversions produce the same result...for `x=010; echo $((x += 1))` the output must be 9. For the commands: `x=' 1'; echo $((x += 1))` the results are unspecified. For the commands: `x=1+1; echo $((x += 1))` the results are unspecified.* ...is that what you mean by *under discussion?* is there more?

Comment: @garethTheRed - the errors you'll usually run into with `$((${expansion} +?op))` are related to the expansion's value not making any sense in that context - particularly if a var is empty. You did `x=$(($x+1))` - probably on an unset `x` and probably hit an *expecting operator* error or something becuase it was just `x=$((+1))`. Still, in the process you set the value - likely to zero - and so it worked the second time as `x=$((0+1))`. *in most cases* you can just do `: "$((x+=1))"` and save worrying about it.

Comment: @mikerserv, see [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/9971) as referenced in the [question that spun off that comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103/22565)

Answer (score 15):

A shell is not a (good) programming language, it's (before all) a command line interpreter. Use a counting command if you want to count, not the `echo` and `[` commands in a loop.

For instance, GNU systems have the `seq` command for that. Alternatives are `awk` or `bc` for instance:

```
seq 50
echo 'for (i=1; i<=50; i++) i' | bc
awk 'BEGIN {for (i=1; i<= 50; i++) print i}'
```

If you find yourself using a loop in shells, chances are you're going for the wrong approach.

Comment: The beauty of Shell is that there are commands to do most things that are commonly useful but hard to implement. In this case, `seq 50` is the one correct answer to OP's question: THIS is how you print numbers 1-50 in shell.

Comment: @SF. If you want shell, `seq` is hardly the 'right' way. `echo {1..50}` (or `printf`) would arguably be the shell way.

Comment: Stéphane, I would only argue with you that there are plenty of times to use loops in bash. Looping is a basic programming construct, and is even applicable in shells (though admittedly, it makes more sense to use a foreach loop in most of those cases).

Comment: @HalosGhost Perhaps Stephane prefers recursion to iteration. :)

Comment: @muru, possible though that may be, I remain unconvinced that looping signals wrong-doing in shell. Additionally, I already said I typically prefer a foreach-style loop in most of those cases (which is often not strict iteration).

Answer (score 11):

> Print numbers from 1-50

```
printf '%s\n' {1..50}
```

print numbers from 1-50 with step say 2 (bash 4+):

```
printf '%s\n' {1..50..2}
```

Comment: +1. Using the Bash builtins and avoiding interpreter-level loops makes this substantially faster than many of the other shell solutions, including my own.

Answer (score 7):

### Use Brace-Expansion Ranges

Other answers may address how to debug your script. This answer shows you a simpler (and less error-prone) way to do what you want using [Bash's brace-expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace#ranges) to generate a range instead of an incrementing loop.

For example, to print the numbers 1 through 50 using this notation, you can use the following snippet:

```
for x in {1..50}; do
    echo $x
done
```

This will correctly print each number in sequence, but relies on features of Bash that aren't portable across shells. If you need portability, consider using *seq* instead.

Comment: Beware that `seq` is not portable either not being part of the POSIX specified utilities.

Answer (score 3):

There is software called [BASH debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net) and other software will be [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) which will give you general errors but not all.

In your script in line 5 use square brackets:

```
x=$[ $x + 1 ]
```

**Update**

Or

```
x=$(( $x + 1 ))
```

former one is depricated, better use latter one. Don't use `$` before `x` which comes before `=` sign

Comment: Just so you know, even though the TLDP Bash beginner's guide recommends this syntax, it is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415724/bash-arithmetic-expression-vs-arithmetic-expression).

Answer (score 2):

From your other question about rounding decimals, I see that you want to do this only in bash. So apart from the other answers, you can do it this way too.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=1
while [[ $x -le 50 ]]
do
    echo $x
    x=$(expr $x + 1)
done
```

Answer (score 2):

On systems with [the `jot` command](http://man.openbsd.org/jot) (BSD systems):

```
jot 50
```

Comment: This works on macOS (which is a BSD system)

Answer (score 1):

`Bash` like `ksh` and possibly some other shells natively supports arithmetic loops:

```
for ((x=1;x<=50;x++)); do
    echo $x
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 50)
do
echo $i
done
```

edit: sorry for posting my answer without reading the tour guide and thanks Stephen Kitt to edit my answer.

So in this script, I get the output of seq 1 50 with command substitution `$()` and iterate that output(sequence of numbers from 1 to 50) with `for`, and print every `i` in that sequence with `echo $i`

And just because you try to print the numbers with loop, I implement it with loop. `seq 1 50` or `echo {1..50}` will give those numbers too, without using iteration.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! Please take a moment to look at the [tour], and [edit] your answer to explain how its specifics (especially compared to the other answers). Also consider how this is different from a plain `seq 1 50` (instead of the loop).