# Can bash indirect expansion be used on a string rather than constructing a temporary variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution

Assuming we've all read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html (specifically, search for **indirect expansion**).

The question means, instead of doing:

```
alpha_date=1563980822; alpha_hash=bfc1a9ad; alpha_url=http://example.com/bfc1a9ad; alpha_path=/build/alpha; alpha_status=failure; bravo_date=1563981822; bravo_hash=f76025c5; bravo_url=http://example.com/f76025c5; bravo_path=/build/alpha2; bravo_status=success; charlie_date=1563982822; charlie_hash=289f55fd; charlie_url=http://example.com/289f55fd; charlie_path=/build/charlie; charlie_status=success

for prefix in alpha bravo charlie; do
    for suffix in date hash url path status; do
        tempvar="${prefix}_${suffix}"
        echo -n "$tempvar: ${!tempvar}"$'\t'
    done
    echo
done
```

This works and outputs:

```
alpha_date: 1563980822      alpha_hash: bfc1a9ad      alpha_url: http://example.com/bfc1a9ad      alpha_path: /build/alpha        alpha_status: failure
bravo_date: 1563981822      bravo_hash: f76025c5      bravo_url: http://example.com/f76025c5      bravo_path: /build/alpha2       bravo_status: success
charlie_date: 1563982822    charlie_hash: 289f55fd    charlie_url: http://example.com/289f55fd    charlie_path: /build/charlie    charlie_status: success
```

I'd like to skip creating the `tempvar` something like this:

```
for prefix in alpha bravo charlie; do
    for suffix in date hash url path status; do
        echo -n "${prefix}_${suffix} is ${!${prefix}_${suffix}}"$'\t'
    done
    echo
done
```

But of course I get a `bad substitution` error from bash.

Is there any way to do bash **"indirect expansion"** on a "string"?

Comment: This question would be a poster child for why we should be using arrays.

Comment: Of course my example is contrived. In the real situation arrays are not an option.

Comment: Why not? Is it an outdated bash? If so, you probably should include that in the question.

Comment: Because the code contrived as an example of the problem. Not the real problem code.

Comment: Why are arrays not an option? What does your data look like, then?

Comment: Dear Stack Exchange community, It's okay that the answer to a question be "that's not possible". You don't have to downvote the question. Nearly every question I ask on here is for something that is not possible. That is because I am **excellent** at solving problems (or finding answers), and if I have to ask, it's probably impossible. If it were possible, I would have probably found the answer in the extensive research and trial and error I do before asking.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways if you want to set the variable (`read "$a$b"`, `printf -v "$a$b" ...`, `declare "$a$b"=...`, etc.).

If you want to read the value, it can be done if the final value is a number, using arithmetic expansion, because arithmetic expansion can be nested (but also see [Security Implications of using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103/70524)):

```
$ a=a b=cd acd=10
$ echo $(($a$b))
10
```

In general, bash doesn't support nested substitution.

Of course, your toy example can be somewhat mimicked:

```
for prefix in alpha bravo charlie; do
    for suffix in date hash url path status; do
        declare -p "${prefix}_${suffix}"
    done
done
```

Or you can play around with `eval`:

```
eval "echo \"${prefix}_${suffix} is \${${prefix}_${suffix}}\""
```

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that `eval` was the only alternative. I'm going to have to avoid that in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `brace expansion` to build the variable names:

```
for i in {alpha,bravo,charlie}_{date,hash,url,path,status}; do
  echo "$i is ${!i}"
done
```

Comment: I'm aware of this kind of expansion and use it all the time. But I've never done a N dimensional use like this. This blew my mind. I'm going to retrofit this into a few projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If using `ksh93` instead, you could do:

```
data=(
  [alpha]=(
    [date]=1563980822
    [hash]=bfc1a9ad
    [url]=http://example.com/bfc1a9ad
    [path]=/build/alpha
    [status]=failure
  )
  [bravo]=(
    [date]=1563981822
    [hash]=f76025c5
    [url]=http://example.com/f76025c5
    [path]=/build/alpha2
    [status]=success
  )
  [charlie]=(
    [date]=1563982822
    [hash]=289f55fd
    [url]=http://example.com/289f55fd
    [path]=/build/charlie
    [status]=success
  )
)
for prefix in alpha bravo charlie; do
    for suffix in date hash url path status; do
        printf '%s\n' "$prefix, $suffix, ${data[$prefix][$suffix]}"
    done
done
```