# conditional binary operator expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variable, test

```
var="$(command1 -l '$var2' -c 'command2|grep -c "search"')"
if [[ var !=0 ]]; then
fi
```

Why am I getting "conditional binary operator expected". I searched already and. I. see that [[]] is a test statement but why would it not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're missing `$` in front of var when you call it, like you wrote it, it will be literally `var`.
2. Consider [possible vulnerabilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103) of your script when using `[[ ... ]]` or `(( ... ))` together with variables you cannot control. In your case, it might be better to use `[ "$var" -ne 0 ]`.
3. You're missing a space between `!=` and `0` (this is the source of the error!)
4. `!=` is a [string comparison operator](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031), while it might work in your example, you want to use `-ne` to compare integers.

Make use of [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Note that `(( var !=0 ))` would also work here, but like `[[ "$var" -ne 0 ]]` would be an arbitrary command injection vulnerability if the nature of the output of the command being captured is not under your control.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane for your insights. Do you consider `[[ "$var" -ne 0 ]]` unsafe? What about the same without quotes? So, what you think should be preferred?

Comment: In `[[ $var -ne 0 ]]` (with or without the quotes, the quotes being not necessary in this particular case) or `(( var!=0 ))`, the contents of `$var` is evaluated as an arithmetic expressions and [bad things can happen then](/q/172103). `[ "$var" -ne 0 ]` (the quotes being necessary here as `[` is an ordinary command) is safe in `bash` (but not all other shells), as `$var` is interpreted as a decimal integer only. `[ "$var" != 0 ]` (or the `[[ $var != 0 ]]` kshism) is safe as well but would return true if `$var` contains `00` as it's a string comparison.